How to Prove a Set is Closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the product topology definition?
Question: I'd like to prove that the set $A= \left\{ (x,\frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the product topology.
Although it can be shown that $A$ is closed by verifying that it contains all its limit points or by demonstrating that $A$ is the pre-image of the closed set $\{1\}$ under the continuous function $f(x,y) = xy $, these approaches require knowledge of the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I am specifically looking for a proof based on the definition of the product topology, using the canonical projections $p_i : \prod X_i \rightarrow X_i $. For instance, considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with an indiscrete topology would render the standard function arguments invalid.
My idea is to show that the complement $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus A = \left\{ (x,y) : xy \neq 1 \right\}$ is open. Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ab \neq 1$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that every $x,y \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \times (b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$, $(xy \neq 1)$. The intervals $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ and $(b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$. Using the product topology's definition, $p_1^{-1}[(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)] \cap p_2^{-1}[(b - \epsilon, b + \epsilon)] $ is an element of the basis, making $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ expressible as a union of such sets, which implies it is open.
Is my proof correct or has someone another idea to prove that $A$ is closed.

Your proof is correct. As you mentionned, in that case there are much quicker options ; but it is still a good exercice to check that the whole theory makes sense. Moreover, once you move to less intuitive topologies (e.g. non hausdorff spaces), you have no choice but to use arguments such as the one you presented here.

As mentioned by the other comment, this is correct, usually the step where you talk about the subbasis and expressing the set as a union, is left out, it's fairly simple and not necessary to repeat the argument that a set is open iff it is a neighbourhood of each of it's points

Your proof is incomplete. How do you know there exists such $\epsilon$? You didn't give it explicitly nor justify its existence in any way...

@user176372 This might look similar since it's dealing with closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but none of the answers answers my question in proving this based on the definition of the product topology.

You made that argument in your previous question and the comments and it was still closed. Disagreeing with the conclusion isn't a justification for trying to circumvent the site's quality control mechanisms.

@user176372 If I start with nothing but the definition of a product topology then simply arguing with the continuity of multiplication isn't very fruitful

If you want to go down the rabbit hole, then you really should explain why

there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $(x,y)\in (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\times(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, we have $xy\neq 1$.

Note that by definition of the product topology, the projections $p_i:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ are continuous. The only thing left to show is why their pointwise product $m=p_1\cdot p_2$ is continuous. Proving continuity of this map is essentially the same thing as showing the existence of the $\epsilon$ above. So, you haven’t really avoided what you wanted to avoid (nor can you).

also, for any normed vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}\in{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}}$, one really ought to prove very early on that scalar multiplication $m:\Bbb{F}\times V\to V$ and vector addition $\alpha:V\times V\to V$ are continuous maps. If you don’t prove this right at the beginning, then almost every ‘basic’ exercise from here on out will consist in decent part, in proving these statements (in some hidden convoluted manner), so really it’s a lot of unnecessary extra effort (though I guess you may need to go through this in order to truly appreciate things).

I see your point. The $\epsilon$ I'm using is simply the $\delta$ from an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)=xy$ is continuous. There is however the difference, and that is maybe my problem, that in an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof we already know the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

The topological way of proving continuity would be to show that for every open set $B$ (or every element of a basis) in $\mathbb{R}$ the pre-image of $f^{-1}[B]$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Since I know how the subbasis and basis of the product topology look alike this should be as simple as writing the pre-image as union of these elements. However this is where I'm stuck.

@bayes2021 then first show that the two definitions of continuity are equivalent (and do not restrict yourself to the plane here; prove it in general product of metric spaces at least). Like I said, if you don’t prove these basic facts first, then you’re wasting lots of time. Also, the equivalence of these definitions becomes almost obvious once you think a little about what it’s trying to say.
